# I wouldn't call myself vs I don't want to call myself

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say you were asked by one of your relatives.

> Question:Are good at using technology?(computer)
>
> Answer#1: Well, I **wouldn't** call myself a computer buff, simply because I still have so much *rooms* to learn.
>
> Or
>
> Answer#1: Well, I **don't want to** call myself a computer buff, simply because I still have so much *rooms* to learn.

What do the #1 actually **mean?** Is this just a style to be polite(would) or a hypothetical answer?

Comment: Side Note: It should be "room" (singular) as in "*space* to learn", instead of "rooms" (plural) as in "rooms of a house".

Comment: In principle, #1 means ***IF** I were required to categorise myself, I wouldn't choose to say I'm a computer buff*. In practice, there wouldn't be any difference in meaning between any of *I **wouldn't / couldn't / don't want to / wouldn't want to / etc.** call myself [category I don't consider myself to be in]*.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here are examples of expressions of "pro-social" expressions.

In the context of your examples:

### Answer #1, what the person is really saying

> Yes, I'm good at using technology.

### What's "non-social" about it?

"I'm good at using technology" can be interpreted as boastful, depending on the listener.

### "Pro-social" version

> "Well, I wouldn't call myself a
>   computer buff (if anyone asked me) because I have so much to learn... (unspoken brag: but in reality, I'm really good) " -> (Generally) "Well, I wouldn't call myself
>   an expert (if anyone asked me)... (unspoken brag: but in reality, I'm really good)

This example is an example of a "humble brag", so that the speaker doesn't seem overtly full of himself.

### Side note: another example of a "pro-social" expression

The "pro-social" expression "I don't want to/I don't mean to..., but..." is used to make the speaker seem more considerate to the listener before he/she reveals something that's difficult to hear. Example:

> I don't mean/want to be rude, but can you please speak more quietly?

Comment: I have never heard or came across this ''pro-social expression'', is this still English or psychology term? You're a native right? Or just in an english speaking country?

Comment: Yeah, native English speaker. I came up with it on-the-fly for purposes of explanation (to mean something that encourages smooth social communication), and confirmed that it meant something close to the definition here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prosocial. I'm not using it strictly as a psychology term, nor as an English language term, which is why I put the term in quotes.